# Can a map overlay be moved?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm displaying several user's locations on a map simultaneously as circles of different colors.

I can do this using an annotation and then when the user's location updates use UIView:animateWithDuration: to move to their new location.

However there is a requirement that the size of the circles reflects the accuracy of the location i.e. very accurate equals a circle of size 10 meters, rough accuracy is represented as a circle of size 500 meters etc.

However there are two problems using annotations for this - the first is how to transform meters into a CGRect on the correct size to draw on the map. And the second is the annotations need to be resized if the user zooms the map.

So I was looking at using an overlay instead as that already has a radius and automatic resizing during zooming built in so it handles those two problems.

However it looks like overlays are meant to be static and their coordinate property is read only.

Is there some way I can make the overlays move as the user's location moves? (other than completely remove it and re-add it?)

[THis is for iOS 7 only]